# Is there a way to get results for an overpass query paginated?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Let's say I want to get restaurants in Berlin and I have this query:

```
[out:json];
area["boundary"="administrative"]["name"="Berlin"] -> .a;
(
    node(area.a)["amenity"="restaurant"];
); out center;
```

Let's say this result set is too big to extract in just one request to overpass. I would like to be able to use something like SQL's `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` arguments to get the first 100 results (0-99), process them, then get the next 100 (100-199) and so on.

I can't find an option to do that in the API, is it possible at all? If not, how should I query my data to get it divided into smaller sets?

I know I can increase the memory limit or the timeout, but this still leaves me handling one massive request instead on n small ones, which is how I would like to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OFFSET` is not supported by Overpass API, but you can limit the number of result this is getting returned by the query via an additional parameter in the `out` statement. The following example would return only 100 restaurants in Berlin:

```
[out:json];
area["boundary"="administrative"]["name"="Berlin"] -> .a;
(
    node(area.a)["amenity"="restaurant"];
); out center 100;
```

One approach to limit the overall data volume could be to count the number of objects in a bounding box, and if that number is too large, split the bounding box in 4 parts. counting is supported via `out count;`. Once the number of objects is feasible, just use `out;` to get some results.

```
node({{bbox}})["amenity"="restaurant"];
out count;
```

Comment: Although this is pretty good, it's not exactly what I need. But if it's not possible to use offset I guess this is the only option. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, can you provide documentation or code to  show how to programmatically split the bounding box in smaller part . Especially in case you have an explicited area as London, how do you break in smaller part?